# What additional paperwork do I need to complete after I become a US citizen?

Tags: usa, citizenship, social-security

After I become a US citizen and I obtain my Certificate of Naturalization, are there any other processes that I need to complete? I have heard that I might need to go to the Social Security office, why?

Answer (score 9):

There are a few things you can do:

- inform Social Security you are now a citizen: ["If your immigration status changed or
  you became a U.S. citizen, you should
  tell Social Security so we can update
  your records."](http://www.ssa.gov/pubs/10002.html#immigration)  This ensures the records are accurate.  In some states, some disability benefits are restricted to citizens only.
- get a [US Passport](https://www.usps.com/shop/apply-for-a-passport.htm) or passport card.  In some states, you may also have the option to update your enhanced drivers licence.
- [register to vote](http://votesmart.org/). Even if you're not sure that you'd vote for any of the current choices, it may be useful at a local level.

A website with more details about these, and other subjects like jury service, is [newcitizen.us](http://www.newcitizen.us/).

Comment: Enhanced driver's licenses are proof of US citizenship, so a new US citizen would have the option to apply for one, but not to update one.  See http://www.dhs.gov/enhanced-drivers-licenses-what-are-they

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons why you may need to go to the Social Security office after obtaining Naturalization in the US.  One of the most common is that you are allowed to change your name when you become a citizen.  So if you availed yourself of this you will need to change your name on all pieces of official documentation that you have.

Another reason would be if your Social Security card contains a notice: "**FOR WORK ONLY WITH DHS AUTHORIZATION**"(or similar), which you can apply for a replacement that won't have this printed on it.

Beyond that the only thing you may need to do is obtain a US passport.

Comment: Even if you don't have either of those reasons (most people don't change their name, and most people already had the "DHS authorization" note removed when they were permanent residents), you should still update your records with Social Security.